# Minimal sufficient statistic for Uniform$(\theta, 2\theta)$, is it a complete statistic?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I know
$$f_\theta(\vec{x})=\frac{1}{\theta^n}\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{I}_{(\theta,2\theta)}(x_i)\hspace{0.5cm}\theta>0$$

and this function  is equals to

$$f_{\theta}(\vec{x})=\frac{1}{\theta^n}\mathbb{I}_{\left(\frac{x_{(n)}}{2}, x_{(1)}\right)}(\theta)$$

Then the rate
$$\frac{f_\theta(\vec{x})}{f_\theta(\vec{y})}=\frac{\frac{1}{\theta^n}\mathbb{I}_{\left(\frac{x_{(n)}}{2}, x_{(1)}\right)}(\theta)}{\frac{1}{\theta^n}\mathbb{I}_{\left(\frac{y_{(n)}}{2}, y_{(1)}\right)}(\theta)}$$
is independent of $\theta$ if and only if $x_{(1)}=y_{(1)}$ and $x_{(n)}=y_{(n)}$, so
$$T(X)=(X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$$
is a minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$

Now for the completness first I should finf $E_T[g(t)]$ and then if $E_T[g(t)]=0$  just when $g\equiv 0$ if means $T$ is complete statistic.

How ever for the case $X$ random sample from $U(\theta, 4\theta)$, my teacher first found $E[X_{(1)}]=\theta(n+4)(n+1)^{-1}$ and then $E[X_{n}]=\theta(4n+1)(n+1)^{-1}$, so for example if
$$g(t)=(4n+1)x_{(1)}-(n+4)x_{(n)}$$
then
$E[g(t)]=0$ but $g\not\equiv 0$ so $T$ is not complete for $\theta$

I don't know why the second method is equivalent to the first and for $U(\theta, 2\theta)$ I am almost sure that $T$ is not complete too. Should I do the same method of my teacher?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To show a statistic is not complete, one only needs a counterexample which is what was done by your teacher. Use the same argument to prove that $T$ is not complete.

Answer (score 2):

First observe that $f(x|\theta)$ is the density of a ["scale family"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Location%E2%80%93scale_family) and the statistic

$$g(T)=\frac{X_{(n)}}{X_{(1)}}$$

is "scale invariant". Thus for a known theorem, $g(T)$ is ancillary for $\theta$ (its distributions does not depend on $\theta$) and thus, $\forall \theta$

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{X_{(n)}}{X_{(1)}} \right]=c$$

and therefore

$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{X_{(n)}}{X_{(1)}} -c\right]=0$$

but clearly

$$\mathbb{P}\left[ \frac{X_{(n)}}{X_{(1)}} -c=0\right]\ne 1$$

This shows that $T$ is not complete